# Is it possible to bind a jquery call to two CSS selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, call

I want to bind a `mouseout` call to two CSS selectors so that if I've moved my mouse from one AND the other element, then I call something else. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like

```
$("#selector1, #selector2").bind("mouseout", function(){
    // code goes here
});
```

Read [**`Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)`**](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.class1, .class2').mousemove(callbackFunction);
```

jQuery selectors work just like CSS. Just use a comma to separate the classes.